# In Eclipse, in the stack trace console, how can I follow links with special characters

Tags: java, eclipse

If the stack trace contains a typical line like:

```
at com.example.Math.introduction(Math.java:101)
```

Eclipse underlines the "Math.java:101" and allows me to click to follow the link to the correct file and line number.

If I have a line with special characters like:

```
at com.example.Français.débutant(Français.java:101)
```

Eclipse does not detect the class reference.

Is there a configuration or something to do for this to work?

Comment: Bug fixed : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489365

Answer (score -2):

Not exactly a perfect answer but you should really prefer naming using ASCII. You can easily head straight into trouble using unicode even today.